# Express, Sequelize error when trying to display and /:id route

Tags: javascript, express, compiler-errors, sequelize.js, nan

I keep getting this error when I'm trying to get a specific route using req.params.id:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'NaN' in
>   'where clause'

The request for the Id is saying this:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `UserId`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Username`, `Password`, 
`Email`, `Admin`, `Deleted` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE `users`.`UserId` = NaN;

 router.get("/admin/editUser/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  let userId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  let token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    authService.verifyUser(token).then(user => {
      if (user.Admin) {
        models.users
          .findOne({ where: { UserId: userId }, raw: true })
          .then(user => res.render("editUser", { user: user }));
      } else {
        res.send("unauthorized");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you verified that `req.params.id` has a value and that `parseInt` is correctly parsing it?

Comment: why is field is single quoted ,

Comment: Show us your `curl` command to execute this handler and please send the model of the table to see the types of the column. BTW, you're not catching the error with `.catch()` after `then` and you should validate that userId was parsed successfully before you make any progress as @MattU mentionded.

Comment: <div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <a class="btn" href="/users/posts">
            Posts
        </a>
        |
        <a class="btn" href="/users">
            Users
        </a>
        |
        <a class="btn" href="/users/admin">
            Admin
        </a>
        |
        <a href="/users/logout">
            Logout
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="userInfo">
    <h1>Hello, {{users.FirstName}} {{users.LastName}}</h1>
    <h3>Username: {{users.Username}}</h3>
</div>

Comment: It's definitely not parsing. I've trying putting the parse in various locations and it still doesn't work. It's not putting the value of the user in the url place holder either.


Here's my Handlebars view:

    <div id="userInfo">
        <h1>Hello, {{users.FirstName}} {{users.LastName}}</h1>
        <h3>Username: {{users.Username}}</h3>
    </div>

Comment: Here's my Model:
`
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const users = sequelize.define('users', {
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    Username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    Password: DataTypes.STRING,
    Email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    Admin: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {});
`

Comment: Sorry this is my first question and I'm not sure how to format things